# What does InvalidExecutableErrorCode 193 mean (visual studio 2010 c# running coded ui tests)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

The application starts and allows logging in but the `code ui test` doesn't seem to recognize the application window.

**Message:**

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ApplicationUnderTest.InvalidExecutableErrorCode 193
```

Comment: Is this a web application or desktop under test?

Comment: This is a desktop application.

Comment: Could you post the code related to the search properties for the window you're searching for and how you're defining `ApplicationUnderTest`.  It's possible you're using WinControls instead of XamlControl or WpfControl, or vice-versa.

Comment: ApplicationUnderTest is defined as 
ApplicationUnderTest root = new ApplicationUnderTest();
Process process = null;
Process[] myProcesses = null;
myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(PCSamplingAppBL.ProcessName);
if (myProcesses != null && myProcesses.Length == 1)
{
  process = myProcesses[0];
}
if (process == null)
{
  root = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(sampling.samplingAppURL);
}
else
{
  root = ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess(process);
}

Comment: The code related to the search properties is

PropertyExpressionCollection pec = new PropertyExpressionCollection();
pec.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.TechnologyName, MSAA_TECHNOLOGY);
pec.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, WINDOW_TYPE);
pec.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "SAF.LShell");
sampling.Window.SearchProperties.AddRange(pec);